# Formatting cells in an HTML table for an Outlook email

Tags: html, vba, outlook, html-email

My macro sends an Outlook email using Excel and VBA.  The email contains a table with details for the recipient.  It works well but the next step is to make it look more professional.  As I've mentioned before, I haven't done much with HTML yet, so this is part of my learning curve.

I have a couple of questions about the code I'm using and am could use some help with formatting the table.

- This line sets up the table.  I'm curious about the 60% and what it
  refers to?  The email page width?

  "<table style=""width:60%"">"
- This line sets up a detail row.  What does the 10% refer to?  The
  table width?

  DataRow = DataRow & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Worksheets("Macro").Cells(vStartRow, 4) & ""
- I'm having trouble aligning data.  I'm not sure how to add a 2nd
  property (?) to specific cells.  I'd like to center align the data in
  the first 3 columns (Customer #, RA #, and Date) and then right align
  the Amounts (like you would typically see in Excel).

Following is the code to create the table detail:

```
DataRow = DataRow & "<tr>"
DataRow = DataRow & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Worksheets("Macro").Cells(vStartRow, 4) & "</td>"
DataRow = DataRow & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Worksheets("Macro").Cells(vStartRow, 5) & "</td>"
DataRow = DataRow & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Format(Worksheets("Macro").Cells(vStartRow, 6), "mm/dd/yy") & "</td>"
DataRow = DataRow & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Format(Worksheets("Macro").Cells(vStartRow, 7), "#,##0.00") & "</td>"
strRows = strRows & "</tr>"
```

I've attached a picture of some sample data so you can see what I'm looking at.  Any suggestions of links to other solutions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for staking the time to share your knowledge and experience with me........

[image]

Comment: Personally, I would just use a raw table without setting any widths, and then style it using CSS (You can do that in an email too)

Comment: At the top of where you are building your `DataRow` String (before where you start the table), put something like `DataRow = DataRow & "<style> table td {width:100px;} </style>"` instead if you want to try it.

Comment: (1) 60% of the page width, but if too much content it will be wider than that  (2) 10% of the total table width  (3) for left/right/center alignment `text-align: right` etc   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious about the 60% and what it refers to? The email page width? `"<table style=""width:60%"">"`

This table will be 60% width of the parent (the tag before it).

> This line sets up a detail row. What does the 10% refer to? The table width? `DataRow = DataRow & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Worksheets("Macro").Cells(vStartRow, 4) & ""`

Since the width is on the `<td>` then it's going to refer to the width of that specific column.

> I'm having trouble aligning data. I'm not sure how to add a 2nd property (?) to specific cells. I'd like to center align the data in the first 3 columns (Customer #, RA #, and Date) and then right align the Amounts (like you would typically see in Excel).

To align text, you can use CSS, and contrary to @braX, you will need to specify this 'inline', i.e. `style="text-align: center"`, not using `<style>...</style>`. This is because some email clients remove `<style>...</style>` sections.

Therefore you can write `DataRow = DataRow & "<td width='10%' style='text-align:center;'>"`

**Watch out**
You will also find difficulties viewing this on mobiles, because the table is lengthy. Consider a 'card' format, e.g. https://medium.com/@nathankeenmelb/responsive-datatables-through-card-ui-design-for-email-aca6f3c395a2